# mock CakePHP configure::read()?

Tags: cakephp

I am using CakePHP 2.x and I want to write unit tests.

In the controller there are several places where exists a read from the Configuration file, like:

```
$dInterval = Configure::read('myapp.dinterval');
```

Is there a way to mock that value for the test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, such a hard coded static call cannot be mocked, at least not in the context of how the application, the framework, and PHP in general work. Technically it's possible to create mocks for static calls using an aliased class, but that would require to set up the alias outside of the test environment, as it needs to happen before the original class is being loaded.

What you can do however is simply write to the config before testing the action, eg

```php
Configure::write('myapp.dinterval', 123);

$result = $this->testAction(/* ... */);
```

The original configuration is backed up *before* each test, and it is being restored *after* each test.

Comment: Static calls should not need mocking.
So jep, this is the correct answer, just add whatever you need before running the test.

Comment: I didn't know that the configuration is saved. What happens if I set a breakpoint and close the debugging using ctrl-C, or if the test crashes?

Comment: @justadev I'm not sure what your question is aimed at? "_happens_" in terms of what exactly?

Comment: What happens to the value of the original configuration parameter. If I overwritten it in the test, then the test crashes, will the original value be restored?

Comment: @justadev Nothing happens to it, this is all just runtime values in memory, the process exits, and that's it. Configuration data is only ever changed in the source when using `Configure::store()`.

Comment: That said: You should also reset your Configure changes using e.g. delete()
This way you do not create side effects for other tests.